# Auto reply to email via SES received with SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, automation

I currently have a domain name that I will no longer be hosting on. I will however keep the domain name forever. Is there any way I can setup an automated setup where I recieve email with Amazon SES and it auto-replies a pre-set email to any incoming email on any address on that domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have AWS SES action to run a Lambda function, which auto-replies to the receiver, in response to each incoming email.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda.html